# Is it possible to disable manual publishing of Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, function, version-control

We have an Azure Function and an Azure DevOps Pipeline, the pipeline builds and published the code of the function's repo automatically. We want to escape discrepancies caused by, potentially, people manually publishing a version of the code, from within their Visual Studio, that is not in source control.

How can we ensure that?

Is there a way to disable manual publishing and only allow the Azure DevOps Pipeline to publish code to the function?

I am referring to a person using the "Publish" option in Visual Studio. Is there a way to forbid the Azure function from accepting such a publish?

Comment: I have the same question. How does an organization prevent developers from publishing from their machine directly to an Azure Function App?

Comment: @ericOnline, sadly I don't think Microsoft figured they need to implement such a (basic) functionality.

Answer (score 1):

To stop manual changes to the build, yaml files and pipeline would be to restric access to the build section of the pipeline for all the users.

This way no one will be able to change the pipeline but the admin user will still have access to the pipeline.

To set the permission we have to go to manage security which is under the pipeline tag.
[image]

Then we can select the permission for the users.

[image]

Here each tag represents a permission. Since we want to stop manual deployment we would set `Edit build pipeline` and `Edit quality pipeline` to `deny`.

These permissions can be set for individuals as well as security group.

**Reference:**

[permissions in devops.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/permissions?view=azure-devops)

Comment: I meant manual publishing through visual studio, I have edited to question to clarify that.